# python dataframe: split a row to several rows and add a new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

There is a following dataframe:

```
 id       data           class             text 
 0     1.1,2.2,3.0      a, b, c        1.1 is 2.2 or 3.0 
 1        4.2              d           4.2 is ok
 2        3.5              a           3.5 is good
 3      1.5, 2.7          b, b         1.5 and 2.7 is product 
 4        3                 c           prices is 3
```

I want to split the above dataframe into following dataframe.
for example, row 0: 1.1,2.2,3.0 which class is a, b, c respectively.
so the row can be split into three rows. The same as row 3 can split into two rows. The position columns is the data position in the data column, for example, 1.1 is the position 0 in the [1.1,2.2, 3.0]
The final dataframe which I want is as following.

```
 id       data     position      class             text 

 0         1.1       0             a           1.1 is 2.2 or 3.0 
 1         2.2       1             b           1.1 is 2.2 or 3.0 
 2         3.0       2             c           1.1 is 2.2 or 3.0 
 3         4.2       0             d              4.2 is ok
 4         3.5       0             a              3.5 is good
 5         1.5       0             b           1.5 and 2.7 is product 
 6         2.7       1             b           1.5 and 2.7 is product 
 7          3        0             c              prices is 3
```

Comment: @jezrael could you help me to solve this issue, please!

Comment: This issue has already been solved before, that's why I've marked as duplicate. If you can explain why whatever you've tried (if anything) didn't work, I will reopen it and solve your problem for you.